# Secure data connector - Replacement

Tags: google-oauth

We have a our enterprise email hosted in the Google. Currently we have a contextual gadget embedded inside the email window (gmail) to sync some of email info into our enterprise CRM. This gadget does two things

1. It uses the Google Secure data connector to pull some data from our enterprise application (CRM) and it displays to the user in the gmail window.
2. Then when user saves the data from the contextual gadget, it calls one of our enterprise web service using SDC to push the data into our enterprise application (CRM).

As Secure data connector is deprecated and going away, what are the other alternatives that we have to replicate this functionality? For both pull and push from a contextual gadget.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use new OAuth service.
You can find info here https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: I understand that using OAuth 2.0, we can call the Google APIs. But How can a contextual gadget (in the cloud) can call the service that is hosted inside our corporate network without SDC?